# Android resource linking failed, Daemon: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

Tags: android, build.gradle

Project was running successfully. There was GCM implemented there. Now I want to migrate from GCM to FCM. After some changes now I am unable to run my app.

Added two dependencies to gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
```

And removed this one

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
```

Also added service for FCM in manifest. Now when I start build the project is giving error like below Note: Project has other two modules also.

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  E:\path\to\project\App\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeProductionReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1161: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
E:\path\to\project\App\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeProductionReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1161: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\uname\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\b5fb2115ff6c1237ef65ed02d6f32cff\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        E:\path\android-studio-windows\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        E:\path\to\project\App\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\productionRelease\processProductionReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        E:\path\to\project\App\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\productionRelease\processProductionReleaseResources\out\resources-productionRelease.ap_\
        -R\
        @E:\path\to\project\App\build\intermediates\incremental\processProductionReleaseResources\resources-list-for-resources-productionRelease.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        E:\path\to\project\App\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\productionRelease\processProductionReleaseResources\r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        E:\path\to\project\App\build\intermediates\legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules\productionRelease\processProductionReleaseResources\manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        com.okulyst.vehicle\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        E:\path\to\project\App\app\build\intermediates\symbols\production\release\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

I have tried many solutions,checked my xml files but none worked!
What is fontVariationSettings and ttcIndex here in error? How to check?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Following the official guide https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

Comment: I have checked all the points there. still error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

After too many tries and efforts, now I can run my application.

Actually the error was because of conflict between `com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` dependencies.

1) Keep same version of all `com.google.android.gms:play-services` dependencies

2) Add/keep `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in app level gradle

3) Add `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` in gradle.properties

4) Add/keep `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services'` on latest version in project level gradle

5) Remove all `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` dependencies

and finally changed all xml and java files with androidx controls. Here is changes list from which you can easily use find and replace.

---

```
    /*android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

    android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

    android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

    android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

    android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout

    android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

    android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton

    android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

    android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout

    android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView

    android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

    android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager*/
```